# ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) when testing show method of controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, rspec-rails

I'm trying to write test for show method of controller.

Below is the method:

```
def show
  if current_user
    goal= Goal.find_by_name(params[:id], :include => :projects, :conditions => ['projects.flag = true OR projects.user_id = ?', current_user.id])
  else
    goal= Goal.find_by_name(params[:id], :include => :projects, :conditions => ['projects.flag = true'])
  end

  @results = goal.projects if goal
end
```

Here is the test i have so far:

```
describe '#show' do
  before :each do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @project= FactoryGirl.create(:project, user: @user, flag: 1)
    @goal= FactoryGirl.create(:goal, name: 'goal')
    @goal_association= FactoryGirl.create(:goal_association, goal_id: @goal.id, project_id: @project.id)
    controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(@user)
  end

  it 'search by goal' do
    get :show, id: @goal.name

    expect(response.status).to eq 302
  end
end
```

This test returns the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: get :show, id: @goal.name
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

The error points to `goal= Goal.find_by_name(params[:id], :include => :projects, :conditions => ['projects.flag = true OR projects.user_id = ?', current_user.id])` line.

I'm not sure how to go about with this.
Any leads regarding this will be helpful.

Comment: What Rails version are you using? Your `find_by_name` usage attempt suggests 2.x.

Comment: I'm using rails version 4.1.16 @MarekLipka
I'm not sure how to write the test for this method. Could you help me out.

Comment: Well, check out my answer, it should work. And I guess you should pay attention, how old is the code you're copying from StackOverflow, because a lot of answers are out of date. :)

Comment: it doesn't seem to identify `scope`. i can use `Goal.find_by(name: params[:id])` instead right? @MarekLipka

Comment: I included setting `scope`. But yes, you can.

Comment: sorry i didn't see that. My bad. Thank you. This worked. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use up to date syntax, because I assume you're not using this really old 2.3 Rails version. I suggest something like this:

```
scope = if current_user
          Goal.joins(:projects).where('projects.flag = true OR projects.user_id = ?', current_user.id)
        else
          Goal.joins(:projects).where(projects: { flag: true })
        end
goal = scope.find_by(name: params[:id])
```